# Reading data from ELF file in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, elf

I need to read data from an ELF file or AXF file and search for a data in that file and return its address. 
In Linux I tried `objdump -t filename.axf | grep search_string` and got the result.

How to do that in Perl. I tried Parse::Readelf too but it did not work.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Binutils::Objdump`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Binutils::Objdump).

**hello.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello world!\n");
}
```

**Create ELF**:

```
gcc -g hello.c -o hello
```

**objdump.pl**:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Binutils::Objdump (); # Seems like this module is missing Exporter interface!??

my $search_string = 'hello.c';

Binutils::Objdump::objdumpopt('-t');
Binutils::Objdump::objdumpwrap("SYMBOL TABLE" => sub { mysymtab( $search_string, @_ ) });
Binutils::Objdump::objdump('hello');

sub mysymtab {
    my ($search_string, @lines) = @_;

    for my $line (@lines) {
        say $line if $line =~ /\Q$search_string\E/;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For casual script you can simply do

```
my $search_str = 'minor';
for (grep {chop; s/.*(0x[0-9a-f]+\s+\S*$search_str\S*)$/$1/x} `objdump -t a.exe`) {
  my ($addr, $name) = split / +/;
  print "$name: $addr\n";
}
```